# Swim Times MM:SS.00 Subtraction, and Transferring to Different Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I created a Google Sheet to catalog my swim times and find out how much of a difference I have in time between swims. I have a =query carrying over data from one sheet to another, but it does not carry over times that are set up as MM:SS.00; only times that are SS.00. I also cannot subtract MM:SS.00 times or SS.00 times from MM:SS.00 times. How can this be fixed?